# Ensuring confidential data is protected from Nuget Packages

Tags: visual-studio, security, nuget, nuget-package

How can we ensure that packages downloaded through Nuget Package Manager are *safe* to use with customer confidential data? From what I know is that anybody can contribute to Nuget and there has been some cases where Malicious code was introduced and could've been downloaded through Visual Studio.

We are trying to figure out a way to vet the packages from Nuget to ensure that the packages are safe to use.

Is there any reliable company/source that says that these packages are safe to use?

Or is anybody currently using a vetting process that is working for them? The last thing we want to is to go through each package we use and research on their vulnerabilities because that's time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ensuring confidential data is protected from Nuget Packages

When we publish the NuGet package to the nuget.org, nuget will check each package to determine if it is safe. You can get below message from [the document of nuget.org](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/publish-a-package):

> Before being made public, **all packages uploaded to nuget.org are
> scanned for viruses and rejected if any viruses are found. All
> packages listed on nuget.org are also scanned periodically**.

So the packages from the nuget.org are safe to use.

**Update for comment:**

> Even though the packages are scanned, that doesn't mean they aren't vulnerable. An outdated package could use vulnerable processes that can be exploited.

Your uneasiness should apply to software you obtain from any source, Even software downloaded from 'app stores' (e.g. Apple iTunes, Android Market) could feasibly contain malicious code. NuGet team comes up with conventions and mechanisms for ensuring that Nuget becomes a trustworthy source of software libraries for .Net developers, but still could not guarantee that all packages are **absolutely** secure.

**The ultimate responsibility rests with yourself as a user to ensure that your IT security isn't compromised, and the precautions you take are are crucial**.

There are some precautions which I could like provide to you:

1. Lock in the semantic version number completely. Explicitly specify the major, minor, and patch numbers. Don't assume that new updates will be safe or that their semantic version will be accurate.
2. Use only well known current versions for production.
3. Experiment with anything in a test environment with limited access.
4. Check the vendor.

Frankly, the Microsoft developer community is very different from the typical internet user community where predators are lurking at every corner. Also, the knowledge level of the developer community is considerably higher. If someone knowingly puts out virulent code through trusted channels like Nuget and Github, he or she will be found, exposed and even prosecuted. Software written with an intent to harm cannot be protected directly or indirectly by any agreement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Even though the packages are scanned, that doesn't mean they aren't vulnerable. An outdated package could use vulnerable processes that can be exploited.

Comment: @JustinJmnz, I have updated my answer for your comment, you can check if it help you.